# Flutter, Android, release version keeps showing white padding around app icon when launched at first time

Tags: android, flutter

Perhaps in the new version of Android, when you run the app, the app icon moves to the center of the mobile screen screen and becomes slightly larger and shows the native splash screen as the default. But this has a lot of problems.

I implemented it with [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons), and white padding keeps attaching around the app icon, on the launch screen.

So I just took the old way of changing the **ic_launcher** icon and successfully removed the white padding. But the problem is that when I do `flutte run --release` instead of debug mode, white padding starts to stick again. I'm having a really hard time with this. Anyone know of this issue?